# Create an opaque struct type using the LLVM OCaml API

Tags: ocaml, llvm, php-internals

I'm building a [PHP compiler](https://github.com/olleharstedt/subsetphp) with an LLVM back-end. I will use the Zend type `zend_string` to represent strings. For this I need an LLVM pointer type called `zend_string_ptr` or whatever. How do I create this pointer type with the OCaml LLVM bindings?

For exampel, this PHP code

```
$a = 'asd';
```

should correspond to this C code

```
zend_string *a = zend_string_init("asd", 3, 1);
zend_new_interned_string(a);
```

To make an LLVM double type in OCaml, you would write

```
let double_type = double_type llvm_context
```

And to make a function type which takes 0 arguments and returns a double, you would write

```
let f_type = function_type double_type [||]
```

I've checked the OCaml docs [here](http://llvm.moe/ocaml-3.6/Llvm.html#TYPEllmemorybuffer) and the C++ docs [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StructType.html), but I'm still not sure how to go about this.

What I want is a function type that takes `zend_string_ptr`, `int` and `int` as arguments and returns `zend_string_ptr`.

The generated LLVM bytecode should be something like this

```
%zend_string = type opaque
declare %zend_string* @zend_string_init(i8, i32, i32)
```

where `i8` is the element pointer to a constant string; and then

```
%1 = alloca %zend_string_ptr
```

and so on.

Tips?

**Edit**: Using `named_struct_type` will create an opaque type, which can be inspected using `is_opaque` and `dump_type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines will create the needed pointer type for an opaque struct:

```
let zend_string_type = named_struct_type llvm_context "zend_string"
let zend_string_ptr_type = pointer_type zend_string_type
```